# Batch File Move command to non existent folder

Tags: batch-file

I accidentally executed a move from a file to a folder that doesn't exist.

How can I restore my file?

It is listed with correct file size but without an extension.

Comment: in this case rename it with the original extension !

Comment: Press ctrl+z for undo action when happen

Answer (score 0):

In this case the file was simply renamed `filename.null` (null means nothing), so renaming it to the original filename will fix it (IE: if the original filename was `cats.mp4` just rename the `cats.null` file as `cats.mp4`, and make sure you have extensions view-able in Explorer).